# Operar con números en arreglos

Tags: c

Estoy comenzando en C y lo que sucede es que debo ingresar un numero de identificación que debe cumplir ciertos parámetros ( lo ingresé como una cadena de caracteres). Pero cuando necesito operar con cada numero del arreglo, este no funciona, ya que se va acumulando. Lo que intente es transformarlo primero a número(atoi), pero de ahí es cuando surge el error, se me acumulan y los necesito independientemente. Gracias de antemano.
Solo muestro la parte de la función que declare para ese proceso.

```c
void verificacion_final(char cedula[])
{
    
    int i,j,k,sumapares=0,sumaimpares=0, sumatotal=0;
    int numeros[10];
    char acum[10];
    
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        acum[i] = cedula[i];
        numeros[i]=atoi(acum);
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j+=2)
        {
            sumaimpares += numeros[j]*2;
            if(numeros[j]*2 >= 10)
                sumaimpares += numeros[j]*2 - 9;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No me queda claro cual es el resultado que esperas. ¿Podrías aclarar con más detalles el problema?

Comment: No necesitas `atoi`. Para convertir un *carácter* que representa un dígito en un número, sustrae un `'0'`: `numeros[i]=cedula[i] - '0';` Para verificar que es un dígito, use `isdigit`.

Comment: ¿Quieres saber como convertir un array de caracteres (string) a un solo número?

Comment: @MrDave1999 En realidad es un resultado implícito, pero el problema es que necesito a cada número de mi arreglo individualmente para poder operar con cada uno de ellos, y pensaba que usar 'atoi' me serviría, pero probé imprimiéndolos y salían acumulados tipo: 175, y necesitaba 1, 7 y 5.

Comment: @Sebas Sí es eso, entonces el segundo comentario ya te dijo todo. Debes hacerlo de esta forma: `numeros[i]=cedula[i] - '0';`. Esto convierte el código ASCII a un dígito.